# How to make sure images uploaded with paperclip have unique names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, paperclip, uniqueidentifier

I am using paperclip to save images. I have created an image model to save them to my public director

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file,
                    :url => "assets/projects_description_images/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/projects_description_images/:style/:basename.:extension"


  validates_attachment :file,
                       :presence => true,
                       content_type: {content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]},
                       :size => {:in => 0..50.megabytes}
end
```

However if I add I make an image with the name "main.jpg" and then create another with the name "main.jpg" when displaying the one that was created first it shows up with the second one. I will have no way of knowing the exact name that will be used but I can be certain that there will be duplicates. It would be great if I could have the file name be saved as something like

main_(unique_string).jpg

Any clue how to do this?

Comment: Well, you could use time of day to the ms or ns level, render it as a string, so that main_{timestring}.jpg would be guaranteed to be unique.  As long as you have the name stored, you'd always be able to locate it, but never duplicate it.  If I recall easy to do with Time class.

Comment: See this: http://trevorturk.com/2009/03/22/randomize-filename-in-paperclip

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Andrey Turkin ( trevorturk.com/2009/03/22/randomize-filename-in-paperclip)solved my problem. One thing to note is that with rails 4.2 I had to change
 `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(16)` 
to just

```
SecureRandom.hex(16)
```